# How to find every integer that is the closest to the antilogarithm (10base) for a series of n*0.1 (in Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, logarithm

In my algorithm I want to evaluate if the current integer n happens to be closest to the antilogarithm of any positive multiple of 0.1, so 0.1, 1.0, 1.1, 7.9, 21.5 etc.

Antilog?
AntiLog(x) = 10<sup>x</sup>

I found an online calculator that finds the antilog here: http://ncalculators.com/number-conversion/anti-log-logarithm-calculator.htm but nowhere I could find any examples of doing this in Python, or any other programming language.

If I can't use Python to find the antilog of a series of numbers I would have to resort to storing a list of antilog values in my program, for performance I'm might consider that anyways but nevertheless it would be great to figure out how to do this in code.

**Update:**
With the code from first answer I was able to do it, this code fully demonstrates all I was trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import math

for x in xrange(1, 1000000):
    target = round(math.log10(x),1)
    int_antilog = int(10**target+0.5) #fast round() alternative
    if (x == int_antilog):
        print 'do something at call ' + str(x)
```

Comment: Doesn't Python have a power operator/function?

Comment: ... isn't that exponentiation/power?

Comment: I guess you have problems to find examples because the term "antilogarithm" is very uncommon.

Comment: In other words you wanted to know whether the integer `n` was a exact power of `10`? In this case doing `while x % 10 == 0: x //= 10; x == 1` is simpler and works for all integers(while doing `math.log10` doesn't work if `x` is big enough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has a [power operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) that performs the exponentiation you want to do:

```
def antilog(x):
    return 10 ** x
```

Examples:

```
>>> antilog(0.1)
1.2589254117941673
>>> antilog(3)
1000
>>> inputs = [0.1, 1.0, 1.1, 7.9, 21.5]
>>> outputs = [antilog(x) for x in inputs]
>>> print outputs
[1.2589254117941673, 10.0, 12.589254117941675, 79432823.47242822, 3.1622776601683794e+21]
```

Round and convert to integers in your favourite way, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If k is the closest integer to 10 to a power that's a multiple of 0.1, then `k ≈ 10ᵐʳ`, where m is an integer and `r=0.1`, so `ln k ≈ m r ln 10` and `m ≈ ln k / (r ln 10) = log₁₀(k)/r`.  If `u = log₁₀(k)/r`, then the values of  10 to a power that's a multiple of 0.1 that are nearest to k are 10 to the power `r` times the floor of u or the ceiling of u, as expressed in the following code.

```
import math

def aloghilo(k):
    u = 10*math.log10(k)
    return (10**(math.floor(u)/10), 10**(math.ceil(u)/10))

def isantilog(k):
   (lo,hi) = aloghilo(k)
   return k==round(lo) or k==round(hi)
```

Here is an example of results, via the ipython interpreter:

```
In [13]: [aloghilo(k)  for k in (20,30,40,50,60)]
Out[13]: 
[(19.952623149688797, 25.118864315095795),
 (25.118864315095795, 31.622776601683793),
 (39.810717055349734, 50.11872336272722),
 (39.810717055349734, 50.11872336272722),
 (50.11872336272722, 63.09573444801933)]

In [14]: [isantilog(k) for k in (20,30,40,50,60)]
Out[14]: [True, False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: Hmm I see your code says 20 is a hit and mine said 19 was. I see I was wrongly using int() where I better use roudn()

Comment: now I see using round makes my code almost 30% slower for my purposes I better use int() even if it's a bit off

Comment: You could use int(v+0.5) instead of round, probably with less delay.  Also, if you find the answer useful, please vote it up